# https for main domain and http for all subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I use this code but not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.blahblah\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)\.blahblah\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://blahblah.com/shop.php?id=$1 [P,L]
```

I want all domain www or non www redirect to `https://blahblah.com`

And all subdomain redirect to http :

```
http://b.blahblah.com
http://c.blahblah.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rule should do it :

```
RewriteEngine on

#enforce https for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
#enforce http for all subdomains of maindomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

The first rule block will 301 redirect your `maindomain.com` to the https version. 
The second rule will Redirect all subdomains to http if they are accessed using https scheme  .

Comment: thx. how use `RewriteRule (.*) http://blahblah.com/shop.php?id=$1 [P,L]` ?

Comment: @FAcademy Why do you want to use this ?

Comment: i want load subdomains from php file

Comment: @FAcademy So you want `sub.domain.com/foobar` to load the contents from `maindomain.com/shop.php?foobar` ?